# How to change the value of $_ to what is required inside grep in perl?

Tags: perl, grep

In this code, I want to access the value of the key `{IS-VAR}`, of each element of the array of hashes `@Cleared`. When it enters inside the loop `$_` is set to the value of `$_->{'NAME'}`.

```
if (grep {$_->{'NAME'} eq $entity_name} @Cleared)
{
  **$is_var = $_->{'IS-VAR'};**
  $var_flag = 1 if ($is_var =~ /^TRUE$/i);
}
```

Is there a way to access the value of `$_->{'IS-VAR'}` inside the loop, `$_` being the element of `@Cleared` in this context?

The structure of `@Cleared` is as follows:

```
@Cleared = [NAME => 'xxx',
            TYPE => 'yyy',
            IS-VAR => 'TRUE'];
```

Comment: Your `@Cleared` doesn't make any sense. It's an array, so it cannot be assigned like `@foo = []`. Please give a complete example of the data. Use Data::Dumper if you are having problems with that. Also, what loop are you talking about in the first paragraph? The code is different from what you are describing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using `grep` in an `if` statement. This converts the result of `grep` into a scalar (which will be the number of elements `grep` found).  Thus you don't actually know which elements match.

If you convert it to a for loop, you will be able to access each element that matched; the rest of your code will work verbatim:

```
foreach (grep {$_->{'NAME'} eq $entity_name} @Cleared)
{
    $is_var = $_->{'IS-VAR'};
    $var_flag = 1 if ($is_var =~ /^TRUE$/i);
}
```

However, if you simply want to find whether a single row matched, you could compress it all into a single grep:

```
my $is_var = grep {
    $_->{'NAME'} eq $entity_name && $_->{'IS-VAR'} =~ /^TRUE$/i
} @Cleared;
```

Now `$is_var` contains a count of how many elements matched.  `if ($is_var) {...}` will be true if at least one matched.

`grep` is not the most efficient way to do it if you only need to know whether there is at least one match, however.  Ideally, you should stop as soon as you find a single match:

```
my $is_var;
foreach (@Cleared)
{
    if ($_->{'NAME'} eq $entity_name && $_->{'IS-VAR'} =~ /^TRUE$/i)
    {
        $is_var = 1;
        last;          #break out of the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect! I was trying for that one liner.

Comment: @Sujju I would recommend against trying to combine things into a "one-liner" until you know the language better.

Answer (score 0):

you can try a simpler for loop:

```
for my $cleared (@Cleared) {
  if ($cleared->{NAME} eq $entity_name && $cleared->{IS_VAR} eq 'TRUE') {
    $var_flag = 1
   }
}
```